# How to trigger SonarQube runs of existing Jenkins jobs only once a day

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

Sonar recommends publishing jobs be run only once a day.  We have ~100 existing maven builds triggered by every code checkin (many times a day).  How can I re-use the existing job definitions to publish only once a day?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have only two options:

1. copy jobs and execute them only once a day
2. modify jobs and use timepstamps to determine if SonarQube should be executed

   - call `sonar:sonar` only if timestamp does not exist
   - create a timestamp after finish job using "shell command"

Example:

```
// standard build
...

// SonarQube
directory = /directory-which-not-be-deleted-by-build/timestamps
file = $directory/$JOB_NAME-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')

if [ ! -f $file ];
then
    // execute analysis
    ...

    // create timestamp file
    mkdir -p $directory
    touch $file
fi
```

Of course you should also periodically clean `$directory`:

```
tmpwatch 30d /directory-which-not-be-deleted-by-build/timestamps/
```